# I would like to resize inside labels of a c3 pie-chart

Tags: html, css, c3.js

I'm trying to create edit the font and the size of my pie-chart so I can put it on a TV.

I tried to increase my chart's width and Height, but it doesn't affect the labels or values or the legend. I googled bootstrap documentation but I can't find anything about labels font-size.

```html
<!-- Mainly scripts -->
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom and plugin javascript -->
<script src="js/inspinia.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>

<!-- d3 and c3 charts -->
<script src="js/plugins/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/c3/c3.min.js"></script> 


<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
    <div class="ibox-title">
      <h5>Radar Chart Example</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="ibox-content">
      <div>
        <div id="pie" style="Height:2000px;"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
c3.generate({
  bindto: '#pie',
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 30],
      ['data2', 120]
    ],
    colors: {
      data1: '#1ab394',
      data2: '#BABABA'
    },
    type: 'pie'
  }
 });
```

I would like to see the numbers **30** and **120** and the labels `data1` & `data2` when I'm unzooming my browser to 40% (approximately the expected size to be visible on the TV)

Comment: hi itsnotmyfault, there seems to be a typo in your `#pie` styling. Have you tried `height` instead of `Height`? would you mind creating a [stackoverflow snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or a fiddle with a working copy? All your links are relative and and some don't look relevant to the question at hand. You say you're using bootstrap 4 but `js/bootstrap.min.js` could be a different version, for example.

Comment: I have no idea how to get online links for the actual scripts/library I'm using.

Comment: Could I add a simple zip you could launch on your local computer instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can [inspect elements](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/) using your preferred browsers debug tools to find out how to directly target an element. This is useful for 3rd party libraries, but that's beyond this question.

c3 uses `<svg>` tags to generate their charts apparently. Therefore, most of the information on the chart is captured inside a `<text>` element, as far as I have noticed. You were simply changing the height of the div itself, not the content within.

The quick answer is to target all of those `<text>` selectors and change the font-size like the following:

```js
c3.generate({
  bindto: '#pie',
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 30],
      ['data2', 120]
    ],
    colors: {
      data1: '#1ab394',
      data2: '#BABABA'
    },
    type: 'pie'
  }
 });
```

```css
#pie {
  height: 300px;
}


#pie text
{
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- d3 and c3 charts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.12/c3.min.js"></script> 


<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
    <div class="ibox-title">
      <h5>Radar Chart Example</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="ibox-content">
      <div>
        <div id="pie"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```